# Android -Check Icon over Image view -when Recycler view item is long pressed

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, bitmap, android-imageview

I am trying to show a set of images in recycler view and when long pressed on item, the check icon should
display over the image view (like when images selected in whatsapp) and the same should disappear when clicked again.

I have successfully created onclick listener and onlong click listener in recycler adapter, which is working as expected.Even, I have added color filter when item is long pressed. Issue is only with the check icon appearing over image view. ( I am using glide to display image)

Expectation: Check Icon should appear over the image view with color filter (not replace - image should still be visible around the icon with less opacity)

Things I have tried:

1. Item decoration - recycler view item decoration - this gives check icon but to all of the recycler items. ( I need only when one item is long pressed, I couldn't proceed further on this , becoz I am new to android dev and I did not get grasp of callbacks yet)
2. Draw canvas - I tried to get drawable and draw it on canvas and draw the canvas again on image view

   ```
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(100, 100, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Drawable drawable= main_context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_check_black);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    drawable.draw(canvas);


    holder.file_thumbnail.draw(canvas);  //Inside onlong press listener which is inside onbind view 
                                         //holder of adpater
   ```
3. Directly set Drawable icon to holder image view: I tried this, it worked, but here image will be replaced with drawable, so original image is not displayed anymore

I tried few more things like ViewOverlay from multiple posts , which didnt help either.

Please help me with some example of how to do it

Note: trying in Android 10

Update:

When I tried with frame layout, SETVISIBILITY worked

had 2 image views for actual image and icon, then changed the visibility within
Onlong press click listener, it worked

But no idea why same was not working in case of Card view / Relative layouts

Comment: Do you want something like Whatsapp? image selection, Have a look at [this](https://github.com/akshay2211/PixImagePicker)

Comment: I tried with visiblity already, but with relative layout, let me try this example (frame layout), I appreciate the quick reply

Comment: @rahat: Thanks a lot, its working now, but any idea why it was not working with relative lay out or when I inflated card lay out?

Comment: There is no XML of the layout given, so I can't say what was the issue, I hope what you needed is in the library.

Comment: please don't post a question or related things in the answer section, instead edit the question and information

Comment: alright,thanks for the example, I will go with framelayout